# PHP - exploiting a user input function parameter in eval()

Tags: php

The code:

```
eval("\$var = \"".template("show_{$_GET['in']}")."\";");
```

i tried:

> "); phpinfo()

but it doesn't work.
How can I break it to execute arbitrary code into eval ?

Comment: This question is off topic on this site and should be re-posted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: i asked this in stackoverflow just now, but i think this is related to information security because the subject is about remote code execution.

Answer (score 2):

This is very bizarre construct but it's not the first time someone is using eval for template engine.

It doesn't look to be exploitable from what is shown here because $_GET['in'] is not passed to eval. What is passed to eval() is the result from template().

Maybe there's something inside template which would allow for code execution, but it's not there so there's no way to test it.

Comment: here's what inside the template in another question, it's  the same test , i wish you'll see the comment section in that question as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48599426/php-invoking-variables-from-inside-eval-function